# How to download image from AWS repository using Angular-Ionic

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, ionic4

I'm trying the following: I need to download an image, but for downloading it I need to get an url from backend. That url is from the AWS repository where the image is stored.

My backend (made with Laravel) works properly, but my problem is trying to download the image from my angular-ionic app.

My code is as follows:

clinic-test.page.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {ClinicTestService} from '../../../../providers/services/api/clinic-test.service';
import {ClinicTest} from '../../../../models/ClinicTest';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-clinic-test',
    templateUrl: './clinic-test.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clinic-test.page.scss'],
})
export class ClinicTestPage {
    clinicTest: ClinicTest;
    clinicTestFileUrl: string;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private clinicTestService: ClinicTestService) {
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        const clinicTestId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('test-id');
        this.clinicTestService.getClinicTest(clinicTestId).subscribe(
            clinicTest => this.clinicTest = clinicTest
        );
    }

    getClinicTestFile() {
        this.clinicTestService.getClinicTestFile().subscribe(
            clinicTestFileUrl => this.clinicTestFileUrl = clinicTestFileUrl
        );
    }
}
```

My getClinicTestFile() function calls another function called the same in my **clinic-test.service.ts** as follows:

```
getClinicTestFile() {
  const urlMock = `${this.baseUrl}/${MOCK_CLINIC_TEST_ID}/{s3_clinic_file_id}/download`;

  return this.httpClient.get(urlMock, {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

It always returns the same test url ('https://sghvr.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aATecub3Epkwu1AcDGVgHIcWi1SrZCW9wkYtkTJU'). I have tested that url on Postman and I can see the image.

In my html code I have the following:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid class="ion-no-padding">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col offset-md="3" size-md="6">
                <ion-button (click)="getClinicTestFile()">Descarga Imagen</ion-button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <br>
        <ion-img src="{{clinicTestFileUrl}}"></ion-img>
        <br>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col offset-md="3" size-md="6">
                <ion-label>
                    <h1><b>Paciente: </b>{{clinicTest?.patient.user.name}} {{clinicTest?.patient.user.surname}}</h1>
                    <br>
                </ion-label>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

In the code above I'm trying to show the image on  element.

Well, when I click on the button to download the image  element gets the test url properly on src, but I'm having the following error on my Console:

```
GET https://sghvr.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aATecub3Epkwu1AcDGVgHIcWi1SrZCW9wkYtkTJU 403 (Forbidden)
```

Well, I need help in these 2 points:

- why do Im having that error on my console?
- how can I manage to download my image using the aws url? I've been searching but not succeed.

Sorry to ask these simple questions, but Im not so used to Angular-Ionic yet.

Any hint is welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe is the reason, but how can I see it on Postman? Anyway, how it could be displayed if you need authorisation? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Now I see that in my postman I have the accesskey and secretkey :S Im going to make public my raws repo during tests

Comment: It was, the first problem, making public I can see, but how can I download it?

Answer (score 1):

```
why do I'm having that error on my console?
```

The error is clear which says you don't have access to the file. You would see "Access denied" if you access the URL directly. Use the access keys you have to download the file or make it public. It depends on your requirements but one thing is crucial to understand. The access key on the FRONT-END is available for all users which is a security flaw. What you need is to use your BACK-END. Get the image in LARAVEL using your access key and send it back to your FRONT-END.

For downloading an image:
Add `download` attribute to your link:

```
<a href="link_of_the_image" target="_self" download>Download</a>
```

The attribute downloads the linked file instead of navigating to it. See the browser support here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp